# NPM failed at es-pack-js postinstall script on geo-viewer example from geo-three.js

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js, npm-install

I'm trying to run the code for the geoviewer examples on geo-three.js, this one: https://github.com/w3reality/three-geo/tree/master/examples/geo-viewer

When I try to build the app, as the readme.md indicates, I get this error:
[image: installation error]

If I execute the second command it doesn't work, because of the said previous error. And even if I try to load the index.html in the browser all I get is a blank screen:

[image]

What am I missing? Because all the relative paths for the includes are right...

Comment: It looks like [other people have had the same issue as you](https://github.com/w3reality/three-geo/issues/44) This seems to be an `npm` problem, not so much a `three.js` issue

Comment: I cannot say I'm happy to find out that I'm not the only one with the same problem. I'd rather find a solution for that...